# 5 camera real-time recording with opencv is too slow

Tags: python, opencv, camera, record

I want to record and syncronize 5 camera in real-time
I used opencv, threading and queue

my cpu is i7 9700k

```
import gxipy as gx
import time
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import timeit
import threading
import queue
from multiprocessing import process


device_manager = gx.DeviceManager()
dev_num, dev_info_list = device_manager.update_device_list()

class cam:

    def __init__(self, device, ExposureTime=20000,AcquisitionFrameRateMode = 1,AcquisitionFrameRate=30,Gain=0,Width = 1920, Height= 1920, OffsetX = 1840, OffsetY = 876):
        self.cam = device_manager.open_device_by_index(device)
        self.cam.ExposureTime.set(ExposureTime)
        self.cam.AcquisitionFrameRateMode.set(AcquisitionFrameRateMode)
        self.cam.AcquisitionFrameRate.set(AcquisitionFrameRate)
        self.cam.Gain.set(Gain)
        self.cam.Width.set(Width)
        self.cam.Height.set(Height)
        self.cam.OffsetX.set(OffsetX)
        self.cam.OffsetY.set(OffsetY)
        self.cam.stream_on()

        # self.recframe = 0
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.q2 = queue.Queue()
        self.device = device
        self.write_n = 0
        self.acq_n = 0
        self.show_n = 0
        self.dt = 1./30
        self.acq_stop = False
        self.write_stop = False

    def start(self,frame_num):
        self.frame_num = frame_num
        self.acqth = threading.Thread(target=self.acq_color)
        self.acqth.start()
        # self.showth = threading.Thread(target=self.show)
        # self.showth.start()
    def write(self):
        self.wrth = threading.Thread(target=self._writer)
        self.wrth.start()
    def _writer(self):
        frame = firstTime = vw = None
        print(f'write start{self.device}')
        s_t = timeit.default_timer()
        print(f'qsize{self.device} = {self.q.qsize()}')

        while True:
            if self.write_stop and self.q.empty():
                e_t = timeit.default_timer()
                print(f'write{self.device} = {e_t-s_t}')
                print(f'write_n = {self.write_n}')
                break

            if not self.q.empty():
                frame = self.q.get()
            if frame is not None:
                if vw is None:
                    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
                    fps = 30
                    vw = cv2.VideoWriter(f'./{self.device}.avi',fourcc,fps,(1920,1920))
                    # firstTime=time.time()
                vw.write(frame)
                self.write_n+=1
            # dt = self.dt if firstTime is None else max(0,firstTime+self.write_n*self.dt- time.time())
            # time.sleep(dt)
        
    def show(self):
        frame = None
        print('showing')
        while True:
            if self.show_n>=self.frame_num:
                break
            if not self.q2.empty():
                frame = self.q.get()
                self.show_n += 1
            
            if frame is not None:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame,(320,320))
                cv2.imshow(f'{self.device}',frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(33) == ord('q'):
                    break
            print(f'{self.show_n}/{self.frame_num}')
        print('showing end')
    

    def acq_color(self):
        s_t = timeit.default_timer()
        print(f'acq start{self.device}')
        self.cam.data_stream[0].flush_queue()
        while True:
            if self.acq_n>self.frame_num:
                # self.wrth = threading.Thread(target=self._writer)
                # self.wrth.start()
                e_t = timeit.default_timer()
                print(f'acq{self.device} = {e_t-s_t}')
                print(f'acq_n = {self.acq_n}')
                self.write_stop = True
                self.cam.stream_off()
                break
            one_s_t = timeit.default_timer()
            raw_image = self.cam.data_stream[0].get_image()
            if raw_image is None:
                print("Getting image failed.")
                return None
            rgb_image = raw_image.convert("RGB")
            numpy_image = rgb_image.get_numpy_array()
            numpy_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # cv2.imshow(f'{self.device}',numpy_image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            self.acq_n += 1
            self.q.put(numpy_image)
            self.q2.put(numpy_image)
            one_e_t = timeit.default_timer()
            # print(f'{self.device} = {one_e_t-one_s_t}')





def main():
    if dev_num is 0:
        print("Number of enumerated devices is 0")
        return    
    cam1 = cam(1)
    cam2 = cam(2)
    cam3 = cam(3)
    cam4 = cam(4)
    cam5 = cam(5)
    cam1.start(150)
    cam2.start(150)
    cam3.start(150)
    cam4.start(150)
    cam5.start(150)
    cam1.write()
    cam2.write()
    cam3.write()
    cam4.write()
    cam5.write()
    time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if i record when acquisition is over. my ram memory is not enough and if i record in the same time it takes more than five seconds to save 150 frames with 30fps

i dont know how to do

if i using multiprocessing would it better?

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. What are the performance measures? (Recording one camera, two cameras, etc.) What is your reference system? (Running standalone recording tools, such as ffmpeg, gstreamer, etc.) Why not try multiprocessing? What did you try? (Tuning codec parameters, using other codecs such as x264, using hardware encoders, etc.)